Video File not being found even though correct path was given
I'm new to Android  app development and am trying to add a video file to my Android project interface following a couple of tutorials. I've added an asset folder, under which I've pasted my stock video named "whale.mp4", but the error log shows the file can't be found, I'm not sure why, since I believe I've given the right path in both the pubspec and code file. This is the main.dart file, which links to the video page:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_ip/video.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(
  home: FirstPage(),
));

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Select Grade',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.pink[900],
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
        toolbarHeight: 70,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[50],
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Video()));
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.brown[200],
            ),
            child: const Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/Grade8.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Video.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';

class Video extends StatefulWidget {
  const Video({super.key});

  @override
  VideoState createState() => VideoState();
}

class VideoState extends State<Video> {
  late BetterPlayerController _betterPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSourceType.file,
      "assets/whale.mp4",
    );

    _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(
      const BetterPlayerConfiguration(
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: false,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      ),
      betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _betterPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Grade 1 Chapter 12",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[300],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text(
              "Tens from 10 to 100",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.purple[900],
                fontSize: 22.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              child: BetterPlayer(controller: _betterPlayerController),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

pubspec.yaml:
name: project_ip
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using flutter pub publish. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.0 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running flutter pub upgrade --major-versions. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run flutter pub outdated.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  video_player: ^2.4.5
  better_player: ^0.0.84

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the analysis_options.yaml file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/whale.mp4
    - assets/Chap8G1_SubUptoNine.mp4
    - assets/Grade8.jpg


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

I'm not sure why this happens but this is the error log I'm getting:
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /whale.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:197)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:108)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:258)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1009)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /whale.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:289)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:152)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:178)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       ... 8 more

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):   Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:274)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7758)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:560)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8457):       ... 11 more

E/flutter ( 8457): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, , null)


this video path is error, answer in this package  example https://github.com/jhomlala/betterplayer/blob/master/example/lib/pages/memory_player_page.dart,

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
